# Codeigniter Memcached session storage miss high rate

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, memcached

I use Memcached service for session storage on Codeigniter based project.

As I see on every refresh cache stats updates:

```
**GET:**

 - Hits: +1
 - Miss: +1


**SET:**

 - Total: +2


**DELETE:**

 - Hits: +1
 - Miss: +0
```

**Screenshot of server status**:

[image]

Does anyone faced same with Codeigniter? If yes why on every refresh I have high miss rate.

Also as I see some record is added and removed from cache on every refresh.

Is this `CI` stuff? or maybe I missed something?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Codeigniter 3.0.6 ? There were improvements for memecache in the last two releases. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html

Comment: Yes I use 3.0.6 version

Comment: I removed all lines from code, where i use session input/output, but still face same problem. I guess `CI` itself is reading/writing something, but why it's missed and why I have deletes idk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what's going on: Looks like these mysterious set and delete are session locks.

When I have session stored with `SOME_KEY` while `CI` updates value of this key, it creates temporary record with `SOME_KEY:lock` index, which is alive while write process is active.

So this is why I have high miss and set/delete rate on every refresh.